# Why not specify the z axies in module pcb?

Tags: sensor

I have a 3 axis Accerelometer (MPU6050) PCB,

but the indication in PCB tells it has only X AND Y axis rotation, why??

[image]

Comment: It is hard to draw an arrow in the Z direction on the PC board.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to guess intentions of board maker (maybe not enough space for the silkscreen?), anyway this riddle has a solution.
You can figure out the Z axis from X and Y. Check the figure from datasheet.
[image: MPU6000 MPU6050]

So, looking from top of the board (like your picture represents the board) the Z axis is directed towards the observer and the positive spin goes counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 1):

The z axis doesn't have to be specified, because it can determined from the x and y axes. Per [MPU6050 data sheet](https://store.invensense.com/datasheets/invensense/MPU-6050_DataSheet_V3%204.pdf) page 21, the axes follow right hand rule, so the z axis points towards you in the photo above.